# VBA Set Recordset in a report has error This feature is only available in an ADP

Tags: vba, report, ms-access-2013

I want to set the recordset of an report in access but i get error "this feature is only available in an ADP?

```
Dim qry As String
qry = "select * from templistdecssched"

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString()
.Open
End With

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
.Source = qry
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
.Open
End With
Set Me.Recordset = rs
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

How can I fix this issue? I am using MS ACCESS 2013

Comment: Try this approach: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287437/en-us?spid=2509&sid=904